# Pandas DataFrame filter by multiple column criterias and multiple intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I have checked several answers but found no luck so far.

My dataset is like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Location':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'Place':[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3],
        'Value1':[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'Value2':[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }, columns = ['Location','Place','Value1','Value2'])

Location   Place   Value1   Value2
A          1       1        1
A          2       1        1
A          3       2        2
B          4       3        3
C          2       4        4
C          3       5        5
```

and I have a list of intervals:

```
A: [0, 1]
A: [3, 5]
B: [1, 3]
C: [1, 4]
C: [6, 10]
```

Now I want that every row that have `Location` equal to that of the filter list, should have the `Place` in range of the filter. So the desired output will be:

```
Location   Place   Value1   Value2
A          1       1        1
A          3       2        2
C          2       4        4
C          3       5        5
```

I know that I can chain multiple `between` conditions by `|` , but I have a really long list of intervals so manually enter the condition is not feasible. I also consider `forloop` to slice the data by `location` first, but I think there could be more efficient way.

Thank you for your help.

Edit: Currently the list of intervals is just strings like this

```
A  0  1
A  3  5
B  1  3
C  1  4
C  6  10
```

but I would like to slice them into list of dicts. Better structure for it is also welcome!

Comment: what is the structure of your filter list ?

Comment: Currently it's just strings like this: A, 0, 1, (each line is one interval) but I would like to slice them into list of dicts. Better structure for it is also welcome!

Comment: I updated the question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

First define dataframe `df` and filters `dff`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Location':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'Place':[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3],
        'Value1':[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'Value2':[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }, columns = ['Location','Place','Value1','Value2'])


dff = pd.DataFrame({'Location':['A','A','B','C','C'], 
                    'fPlace':[[0,1], [3, 5], [1, 3], [1, 4], [6, 10]]})


dff[['p1', 'p2']] = pd.DataFrame(dff["fPlace"].to_list())
```

now `dff` is:

```
  Location   fPlace  p1  p2
0        A   [0, 1]   0   1
1        A   [3, 5]   3   5
2        B   [1, 3]   1   3
3        C   [1, 4]   1   4
4        C  [6, 10]   6  10
```

where `fPlace` transformed to lower and upper bounds `p1` and `p2` indicates filters that should be applied to `Place`. Next:

```
df.merge(dff).query('Place >= p1 and Place <= p2').drop(columns = ['fPlace','p1','p2'])
```

result:

```
  Location  Place  Value1  Value2
0        A      1       1       1
5        A      3       2       2
7        C      2       4       4
9        C      3       5       5
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works well on my example dataset. However, on real dataset, where lengths of both interval and dataframe is quite large, the `merge` command consumes too many memory

Comment: Interesting, how many rows is Your real dataframe and filter?

Comment: I got 13300 rows for the dataframe and 10000 rows for the filter

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisites:

```py
# presumed setup for your intervals:

intervals = {
      "A": [
            [0, 1], 
            [3, 5],
           ],
      "B": [
            [1, 3],
           ],
      "C": [
            [1, 4], 
            [6, 10],
           ],
}
```

Actual solution:

```py
x = df["Location"].map(intervals).explode().str
l, r = x[0], x[1]

res = df["Place"].loc[l.index].between(l, r)
res = res.loc[res].index.unique()
res = df.loc[res]
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

  Location  Place  Value1  Value2
0        A      1       1       1
2        A      3       2       2
4        C      2       4       4
5        C      3       5       5
```

Comment: a little silly question from me: how do I create dict with merge key value like that? I tried groupby then apply(list) but it didn't seem to be the right format like you

Comment: As presented above :) what's your original format for it?

Comment: My original format is table-like, as in the post, with each line is one `Location` with interval. There could be many same `Location`.

Comment: Yeah, I used pd.read_csv to read them as dataframe. The "Location" is read as string while the interval is read as integer

Comment: Ah, so `intervals` is also `pandas`, with 2 columns - one `Location`, and the second containing single `list` with 2 `int`-s in each row?

Comment: Actually it has 3 columns for, one for Location, the rest are start and end position of the interval